# Can some explain this code to me?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the working VBA code below. It's listing the missing numbers in a sequence in a new column, but I don't now how the code is working. I don't understand the For loops and the scripting.dictionary.

```
Const rng As String = "$a$2:$a$218"
Dim d As Object, a, c()
Dim i As Long, mx As Long, mn As Long

Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
a = Range(rng)

mx = Application.Max(a): mn = Application.Min(a)

ReDim c(1 To mx - mn + 1, 1 To 1)


For i = 1 To UBound(a): d(a(i, 1)) = 1: Next i

For i = mn To mx
    If d(i) <> 1 Then k = k + 1: c(k, 1) = i
Next i


Range("d2").Resize(k) = c
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: i;m not surprised it is difficult to work it out as whoever wrote it used some pretty cryptic naming conventions (e.g. `rng` is 'traditionally' a `Range` object, not a string) and `a` is not very descriptive (it could be instead, 'initialValuesArr'). Anyway David Zemens' answer breaks it down nicely

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks will tell you about the `Dictionary` object:

http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html

You can also look at documentation here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164502(v=office.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164502%28v=office.10%29.aspx)

What your code is doing...

**Creates the dictionary object and assigns to variable `d`**

```
Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
```

**Assigns the values from specified range constant to a range array, `a`**

```
a = Range(rng)
```

**Determine the minimum and maximum values within the range array, `a`**

```
mx = Application.Max(a): mn = Application.Min(a)
```

**Redimension the array `c` so that it will hold the appropriate number of values between `mn` and `mx`**

```
ReDim c(1 To mx - mn + 1, 1 To 1)
```

**Puts each item from the range array `a` in to the dictionary object, `d`**

```
For i = 1 To UBound(a): d(a(i, 1)) = 1: Next i
```

**Loops from `mn` to `mx`, essentially checking if this value exists in the dictionary `d`, and if not, puts that value in the array `c`.**

```
For i = mn To mx
    If d(i) <> 1 Then k = k + 1: c(k, 1) = i
Next i
```

**Prints the array `c` to the worksheet**

```
Range("d2").Resize(k) = c
```

**Update: Possibly revise to this:**

```
Const rng As String = "$a$2:$a$218"
Sub DoThis()
Dim d As Object, a, c()
Dim i As Long, mx As Long, mn As Long

Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
a = Range(rng)

mx = Application.Max(a): mn = Application.Min(a)

For i = mn To mx: d(i) = True: Next i

For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
    '# You should not actually NEED to use the If d.Exists, 
    ' you can probably just do:
    ' d.Remove(a(i, 1))
    ' but just in case, I test to see if it exists:
    If d.Exists(a(i, 1)) Then d.Remove(a(i, 1))
Next i

Range("d2").Resize(UBound(d.Keys()) + 1) = Application.Transpose(d.Keys())
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, it was exactly what i was looking for, now i can use the code while understanding  what it's doing ^_^

Comment: No problem! The revision I posted should do the same thing but it bypasses two of the loops, and by directly printing the dictionary's `Keys()` (which is already an array!) to the worksheet, we avoid using variable `c` altogether.